# Draw latitude and longitude with polygon on canvas

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, delphi

I have the following points of lat and long

```
-29.8150081639178, -55.74497604370117
-29.8200035090558, -55.74497604370117
-29.8200035090558, -55.74998092651367
-29.8150081641506, -55.74998092651367
```

and would create a polygon on the screen. 
My points are small so I'm having difficulties to transform them into coordinates. Anyone have any tips or code in Delphi, HTML5, HTML5 canvas, or JavaScript using these points?

Comment: Please ask a more specific question. What sorts of difficulties are you having? Post the code you've tried and explain what doesn't work about it. Your question comes across sounding a lot like asking someone else to write code for you, which is not what SO is about.

Comment: Which projection do you aim to use?

Comment: My problem is I use google maps to show the polygonos, but when I'm offline would also show the polygon. As I have the coordinates of lat \ long, I grab them and play on the computer screen. I guess I've been more clear.
I will try to use the code in java posted by friend

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is my take at it, the code is pretty self explanatory and I haven't really optimized the scale method. What it essentially does is displace all the points by coordinates of the point with the largest square and then tries to scale the points so they fit the maximum pixelcoordinates I desire.

```
 import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D;
import java.beans.Transient;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class LatLongDemo extends JPanel {

    private double[][] coords;
    private double[][] coordsScaled;
    private final int maxLatitudeInPixels = 1200;
    private final int maxLongitudeInPixels = 700;
    private boolean scaled;

    public LatLongDemo() {
        Random rnd = new Random();
    double x = -29.8150081639178;
    double y = -55.74497604370117;
    coords = new double[][] {
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() },
            { x + rnd.nextDouble(), y + rnd.nextDouble() } };
        scaleCoords();
    }

    private void scaleCoords() {
        coordsScaled = new double[coords.length][2];
        double maxDistance = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        int indexOfLargestDistance = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < coords.length; i++) {
            double latitude = Math.abs(coords[i][0]);
            double longitude = Math.abs(coords[i][1]);
            double distanceSquared = latitude * latitude + longitude
                    * longitude;

            if (distanceSquared > maxDistance) {
                maxDistance = distanceSquared;
                indexOfLargestDistance = i;
            }
        }

        double displaceLatitude = -coords[indexOfLargestDistance][0];
        double displaceLongitude = -coords[indexOfLargestDistance][1];
        double maxLatitude = Double.MIN_VALUE, maxLongitude = Double.MIN_VALUE;
        int indexOfMaxLatitude = 0, indexOfMaxLongitude = 0;

        for (int i = 0; i < coordsScaled.length; i++) {
            double latitude = coords[i][0] + displaceLatitude;
            double longitude = coords[i][1] + displaceLongitude;
            coordsScaled[i][0] = latitude;
            coordsScaled[i][1] = longitude;

            if (latitude > maxLatitude)
                maxLatitude = latitude;
            if (longitude > maxLongitude)
                maxLongitude = longitude;
        }

        double latitudeScale = maxLatitudeInPixels / maxLatitude;
        double longitudeScale = maxLongitudeInPixels / maxLongitude;

        for (int i = 0; i < coordsScaled.length; i++) {
            coordsScaled[i][0] = coordsScaled[i][0] * latitudeScale;
            coordsScaled[i][1] = coordsScaled[i][1] * longitudeScale;
        }
        scaled = true;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Color getBackground() {
        return Color.black;
    }

    @Override
    @Transient
    public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
        return new Dimension(1280, 720);
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        super.paintComponent(g);
        if (!scaled)
            return;

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
        FontMetrics fm = g2d.getFontMetrics();

        for (int i = 0; i < coordsScaled.length; i++) {
            double originalLatitude = coords[i][0];
            double originalLongitude = coords[i][1];
            double newLatitude = coordsScaled[i][0];
            double newLongitude = coordsScaled[i][1];

            Ellipse2D.Double point = new Ellipse2D.Double(newLatitude,
                    newLongitude, 5, 5);
            String original = "Original: " + originalLatitude + ","
                    + originalLongitude;
            String scaled = "Scaled: " + newLatitude + "," + newLongitude;

            float originalStringX = (float) (newLatitude - fm
                    .stringWidth(original));
            float originalStringY = (float) (newLongitude - fm.getHeight());
            float scaledStringX = (float) (newLatitude - fm.stringWidth(scaled));
            float scaledStringY = (float) (newLongitude + fm.getHeight());

            g2d.setColor(Color.white);
            g2d.drawString(original, originalStringX, originalStringY);
            g2d.drawString(scaled, scaledStringX, scaledStringY);
            g2d.setColor(Color.green);
            g2d.fill(point);
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JFrame frame = new JFrame();
        LatLongDemo latLongDemo = new LatLongDemo();
        frame.getContentPane().add(latLongDemo);
        frame.setResizable(false);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

}
```

[image]

Comment: thanks, I'll try to use the code and then say the end result

Answer (score 3):

Pick a zero point, move them relative to that, and scale by a constant factor.